# How can I have multiple different values to iterate through in the same for statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Error returns ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```py
accounts = [["Tom", "Boyle", "23"]]
for meta in "First Name", "Last Name", "Age":
    for account in accounts:
        # The line below is what I have trouble with
        for info, meta in account, ("First Name", "Last Name", "Age"): 
            print(meta + ": " + info)
            print("------------------------------------------")

            
""" Expected Output:
First Name: Tom
Last Lame: Boyle
Age: 23
------------------------------------------
"""
```

Comment: `zip` is useful here. Iterate over `zip(account,("First Name", "Last Name", "Age"))`. That seems to be what you are trying to do without realizing it.You seem to have too many levels of looping for this to make sense.

Comment: I agree. I'm sure you dont first want ALL the 'First Names', then ALL the 'Last Names', etc.
Therefore having `for meta` as the outermost loop is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
accounts = [["Tom", "Boyle", "23"]]
meta_list = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age"]
for account in accounts:
    for meta, info in zip(meta_list,account): 
        print(meta + ": " + info)
    print("------------------------------------------")
```